# QGIS how can I create a legend with only one set of categories (in common) and two different set of symbols?

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

In QGIS I would like to create a legend with two sets of symbols (for the two overlapping layers which are shown in the map) sharing the same categories. Something like that:

[image]

Is there a way to do it in QGIS in an organized way without copy and paste?

Comment: You can have more than on column in the legend by changing the column item property

Comment: And then don't label the second layer, so it looks like in your example.

Comment: Thanks I found this option. Do you have any ideas of why the two colums however return to be vertically alligned when I save the map as .png?

Comment: Please ask follow-up questions separately.